# How to fetch response headers value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, fetch, axios

I want to fetch the values of **Response Header** after getting the response from **axios**.

[image: Server response]

As you can see in the above image, I want to fetch the value of **Location** i.e. coming under the **Response Header**.
Would you please help me.
Thanks :)

Comment: I'm still not able to fetch the Location value.

Answer (score 0):

As javascript abstracts the XMLHttpRequest object in a so-called "super set" that does not expose the responseURL field. If you are setting a custom header and want to use in your js file then you will need to set the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header with the custom header fields in server side and get in the client side by using getResponseHeader() function.

Comment: Would you please explain it a little bit more. Here is my code `fetch(`${configVar.API_HOST}${configVar.BASE_URL}/permission`, {
    headers: {
      token,
      ...header
    },
    method: 'GET'
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log('res', res.status, res.getResponseHeader() );
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('err', err);
  });`